# Get unique sessions by reading Google Analytics cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, analytics

It is possibile to read the google analytics cookie and use it to understand if the user is a "new session" or in a subsequent page-view?

With "new session" I mean if a users access the website for the first time in the actual session
(no matter if he already visited my website before, in another session)

What I need to do is

```
if( first pageview of the session ) { 
// do something 
} else { // pageview
// do something else
```

I know how to create a new cookie to do this, but I need to get the exact same algorithm used by by google analytics.

Edit:
I was thinking to store the analytics cookie value and then compare it